# Explain the output of this code with nested ranges

Tags: python, list, range

So the code is:

```
X = range(4, 7)
Y = range(2)
X[2] = Y
print X[2][0]
print X[2][1]

X[2][0] = 9
print Y[0]
```

And the output is

```
0
1
9
```

What exactly is the code doing to get that output? Also if the code looked like

```
X = range(4, 7)
print X[-1]
```

Then what would the output be because I'm confused about what negative values do.

Comment: `X = 4,5,6; print 6`, negative index from backwards, starts from -1

Comment: add `print X` before the first `print` and you will understand.

Comment: btw, X[-1], and print won't work that way in python 3, because range is an iterator and print is a function.

Comment: Negative indexes in python start from the end and count backwards, e.g. `[1, 2, 3][-1] == 3`

Comment: Consider reading the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html), in particular, the information you need is on the introduction page.

Comment: I changed the title of your question because at first glance someone could say "just run the code". But I think I see your confusion on why 9 is printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> X = range(4, 7)  # List of number from 4 to 6
>>> Y = range(2)     # List of number from 0 to 1
>>> X
[4, 5, 6]
>>> Y
[0, 1]
>>> X[2] = Y         # Stored 'Y' at X[2] in place of '6'
                     # X[2]  is referencing Y  
>>> X
[4, 5, [0, 1]]
>>> print X[2][0]    # '0'th index of X[2] i.e Y[0] 
0
>>> print X[2][1]    # '1'th index of X[2] i.e Y[1]
1
>>> X[2][0] = 9      # Set '0'th index of X[2] i.e Y[0] as 9
>>> Y[0]
9
>>> Y
[9, 1]
>>> X
[4, 5, [9, 1]]
```

Now coming to your another question related to `negative index`. `-i` as index represnt `i`th element from the last. For example:

```
>>> X = range(4, 7)
>>> X
[4, 5, 6]
>>> X[-1]    # 1st element from last
6
>>> X[-3]    # 3rd element from last
4
```

Comment: I am updating the answer with step by step process :)

Answer (score 0):

if a string has a value say x="Hello" then from left to right those characters are assigned values `0,1,2,3,4` where as from right to left those are assigned `-1,-2,-3,-4,-5` so if you say

```
print x[-1]
```

it will return 'o' and if you say

```
print x[0]
```

it will return 'H' , hope that clarifies.

Comment: You answered the last question, but not the others